# RestKit How to Post an Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm using Rest Kit 0.20.3 and Xcode 5 to create an application. I've completed the GET request and got my 2 objects from the server. Now I've created an additional View with two text fields to enter playerName and playerAge. 
I've tried the following code to post a new player to the server but its not working:

AddPlayerViewController.h

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Player.h"

@interface AddPlayerViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Player *addedPlayer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *playerNameTxt;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *playerAgeTxt;

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
@end
```

AddPlayerViewController.m

```
@implementation AddPlayerViewController

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    [self postObject];
}

-(void)postObject{

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:addedPlayer path:@"/players.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        addedPlayer.playerName = playerNameTxt.text;
        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
        addedPlayer.playerAge = [numberFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",playerAgeTxt.text]];
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];
}
@end
```

I'm getting the following errror:

```
Expected status code in (200), got 422, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xaf67e60> { URL: http://localhost:3000/players.json}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelWarning);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.3:3010"]];

    RKObjectMapping *playerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Player class]];

    [playerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"playerID",
                                                        @"name": @"playerName",
                                                        @"age" : @"playerAge",
                                                        @"created_at": @"createdAt",
                                                        @"updated_at": @"updatedAt"}];



    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDesc = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:playerMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"/players.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDesc];


    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[playerMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Player class] rootKeyPath:@"/players.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    return YES;
}
```

Player.h

```
@interface Player : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *playerID;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *playerName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *playerAge;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDate *createdAt;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDate *updatedAt;

@end
```

On the Server Side I get this:

```
Started POST "/players.json" for 192.168.1.3 at 2013-11-01 20:01:34 +0530
Processing by PlayersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"/players.json"=>{"age"=>"40", "name"=>"sachin"}}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: player):
  app/controllers/players_controller.rb:73:in `player_params'
  app/controllers/players_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Comment: Have you added request descriptor for Player? make sure the object you are posting is not nil.

Comment: RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[playerMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Player class] rootKeyPath:@"/players.json" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];         This is my request descriptor method for Player in AppDelegate.m file
    
    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

Comment: In restkit go to RKObjectManager class, -(id)mergedParametersWithObject:(id)object.. this method creates your request JSON. Try to debug it.

Comment: I couldn't find this method, But does this have anything to do with the other properties that I have for my player object. I've 5 of them. But I'm entering only two.

Comment: In this method you can check, how your request JSON get created. From your request descriptor remove "rootKeyPath" pass nil for that.

Comment: I did that and still getting the same error. In my log I've few lines of HTML code I think...I don't know

Comment: Turn on trace logging for the mapping and see what it says.

Comment: Also, show your mapping. Add code to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: `{
    age = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "2013-11-01T11:04:40.000Z";
    id = 3;
    name = "<null>";
    "updated_at" = "2013-11-01T11:04:40.000Z";
} to object <Player: 0x8dc7bb0> with object mapping (null)

Comment: It is taking both values as NULL

Comment: @Wain Do I have to create a separate object mapping in addPlayerViewController.m

Comment: I have no idea. You haven't given details of the mapping or the contents of `Player`. I'm trying to poke you in the direction of useful information.

Comment: I've provided both in the edited version of my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your server is expecting an object with "player"

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: player):

and you are passing "/players.json"

Parameters: {"/players.json"=>{"age"=>"40", "name"=>"sachin"}}

try changing your post path to just "player" in Xcode

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:addedPlayer path:@"player" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
```

and

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[playerMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Player class] rootKeyPath:@"player" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

Comment: It Worked and got an insert statement from the server but in my app it shows the following error : Expected status code in (200), got 201...But when I refresh my table View I get the updates.

Comment: Thats because 201 is the status code for when you successfully POST, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes     You'll want to add a table refresh line in the `success` block of the post method

Comment: U mean this one : `[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing]`, I've `[self.tableView reloadData]` method in my success block of the post method.

Comment: no [self.tableview reloadData] should be the one. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you want to do this:

```
addedPlayer.playerName = playerNameTxt.text;

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
addedPlayer.playerAge = [numberFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",playerAgeTxt.text]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:addedPlayer path:@"/players.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Yay - life is great!");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Bum: %@", error);
}];
```

---

From your updated log:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[playerMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Player class] rootKeyPath:@"player" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

Comment: And you probably should be removing `@"/players.json"` from your request descriptor.

Comment: should I use nil in place of it

Comment: yes (as per the previous comment from @OMK). Unless there is a reason for you to be nesting. Even if there is it's highly unlikely that you should have a `/` in the key path...

Comment: I've removed / but it still not working...The server shows missing parameter like this : ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: player):

Comment: So please give details -- in the question -- of what JSON is currently generated and what the server is expecting.

Comment: So you added it as a comment anyway. Put it in the question please! And give details of what is currently happening after the changes we have discussed. Why is `/players.json` at the root of the JSON?